# How to get my all friends using spring social facebook template?

Tags: spring, facebook, spring-boot

I am developing project on spring boot and i am using spring social facebook api in order to get user profile and its friends. My code is

```
Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(socialAuthToken);
        org.springframework.social.facebook.api.User facebookUser = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile();
```

above code works fine , it gives me my profile but when i try to get my friends profile it gives only eight user via paging but i want to get all users .
Code to get friends

```
List<String> friendsIds = facebook.friendOperations().getFriendIds();
        for(String id : friendsIds){
            org.springframework.social.facebook.api.User user = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile(id);
            System.out.println(user.getEmail());
            System.out.println(user.getFirstName());
        }
```

Comment: Are you using a non-supported SDK?

Comment: you can only get friends who authorized your app too, you know that, right?

Comment: i am using "org.springframework.social.facebook.api"

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get ALL friends, only those which are USING your app. and NO, there is no workaround.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

> The list of friends returned via the /me/friends endpoint is now limited to the list of friends that have authorized your app.